# npm commands stuck on cmd when running off a UNC path

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I'm currently working on a SPA for my company that I do in Angular 8. The whole solution is located at a UNC path like the rest of our source code as well. When I try `npm install` or `ng new xyz` it goes on for a while but stucks after around 50% and won't continue. The whole command prompt freezes after a while and all I can do is killing it with the task manager.

I tried to set up a test-solution on my local C-drive and it seems to work fine there but what causes this issue at UNC paths? Is there any alternative to make it run on UNC paths?

my npm version is: 7.24.0
my node version is: 14.17.6

Comment: It's probably processing many small files. Network driver as working directory are a terrible idea for npm because of the huge latency compared to a local drive when accessing any file.

Comment: @CherryDT It was running over night (propably 12 hours) because that was actually my first thought and then I noticed that my whole command prompt was dead. I also don't get any kind of warning or anything.

Comment: Any activity in Process Monitor? If not, what is the last activity of node.exe there before it stops? If you look into Process Explorer/Process Hacker and check the node.exe process, is the main thread hanging in a single system call all the time? Do you get anything when you do right click, analyze, wait on the thread? (not sure if this exists in Process Explorer too, but in Process Hacker it does) - What are the last console entries when you run npm in verbose mode? - you can find all mentioned tools with Google

Comment: @CherryDT will take a look tomorrow. thank you for now!